# Neo4j: How can I implement apoc.atomic.update in my cypher statement?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a Cypher import for the first import and the `new_neo_test_1.csv` file that has the following columns: `From`, `To`, `Sender_Sub_Fld`, `DateTime`, `Url`, and `FileHash`

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/new_neo_test_1.csv") AS row
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld, datetime: datetime(row.DateTime) })
MERGE (b:Recipient { name: row.To, datetime: datetime(row.DateTime) })
WITH a,b,row
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false"
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {datetime: datetime(row.DateTime)}, b, {}) YIELD rel as rel1
RETURN a,b
```

My goal is to use something like the following for the rest of the imports.  I would like to update the relationships `datetime` property if the node already exists. Kindof a last seen property.

I have tried variations of `apoc.atomic.update` like the following but cant seem to get it to work.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/new_neo_test_2.csv") AS row 
MERGE (a:Sender { name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld, datetime: datetime(row.DateTime) }) 
MERGE (b:Recipient { name: row.To, datetime: datetime(row.DateTime) }) 
WITH a,b,row 
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false" 
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel as rel1 
CALL apoc.atomic.update(rel1, datetime, datetime(row.DateTime)) YIELD datetime as newdatetime 
RETURN a,b
```

Or if there is another suggestion to solve my problem that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use values that uniquely identify a node in the `MERGE` clauses of your non-first imports. Otherwise, you can cause new nodes to be created. For example, your `MERGE` clauses should omit the `datetime` properties (since their values might change between import files). After each `MERGE`, you can use `SET` to update the `datetime`.

This might work for you:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///sessions/new_neo_test_2.csv") AS row
WITH row, datetime(row.DateTime) AS dt
MERGE (a:Sender {name: row.From, domain: row.Sender_Sub_Fld})
SET a.datetime = dt
MERGE (b:Recipient {name: row.To})
SET b.datetime = dt
WITH a, b, row, dt
WHERE row.Url = "false" AND row.FileHash = "false" 
CALL apoc.merge.relationship(a, row.Outcome2, {}, {}, b) YIELD rel
SET rel.datetime = dt
RETURN a, b
```

*NOTE: There is no apparent need for using `apoc.atomic.update`, so this query does not.*